# CSS Modules: is there a way to reuse react component with different styles

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

React with CSS Module is very delightful, anyway, I have a page on which I want to represent exactly the same components except styling, I do not know how to do this with CSS Module.

In a traditional way, I would like to use different css file links in the "head" on each page, but CSS Modules is bound within it is own component by importing styles, seems there is no way to overwrite it without ruin the other page.

Of course, I can just copy all components and paste in another folder, and import them there, re-write the css files, but a full copies of component seems silly, what if I want to modify any component in these components? then I have to modify all copies.

Is there a graceful way to do this?

Thank you.